Stuck in a redirect loop (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Chrome)
I have a VPS that I administer that is running Apache over CentOS 8.  The server uses Cloudflare as a CDN and proxy.
It has come to my attention that one of the four domains on the VPS is down - it may have been down since they moved to this host several months ago.  I'm not sure.  It's a hobby domain, hasn't been treated with much concern. Now, it needs to be fixed.
Cloudflare was reporting a 521 error - the host wasn't responsive.  I've seen that this can be caused by incorrectly configured DNS or SSL settings, so I turned SSL off on Cloudflare, and for testing, changed all of the various A and CNAME records to "DNS only".  Once I made that change, I now get the above error (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR).
Please note - every time I test, I open a brand new Chrome incognito session so as to ensure that I don't have lingering cookies or whatever.
I've used several redirect checker tools, and I see a redirect loop going on.  Something like:
    http://sample-bad.com - 301 redirect to  
    http://www.sample-bad.com - 308 redirect to   
    https://www.sample-bad.com   

...and off it goes again.
I figured that the culprit must be my httpd.conf file.  I looked at it, couldn't see anything wrong.  So I totally killed the virtualhost entries for this domain.  Stopped and restarted the server, confirmed that the site no longer tried to load.  Cool.
Next stop, I copied a good working site's virtualhost entries, then copy/pasted the correct domain name over the working one.  Behold the new code:
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sample-bad.com
        Redirect permanent / http://www.sample-bad.com/
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@sample-bad.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.sample-bad.com/
        ServerName sample-bad.com
        ServerAlias *.sample-bad.com www.sample-bad.com
        ErrorLog logs/sample-bad.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/sample-bad.com-access_log common
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


    <Directory "/var/www/html/www.sample-bad.com">
      AllowOverride All
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

That is identical to a good, working domain.
I had a one line .htaccess file that allows xml files to be read with php.  For testing, I removed the file altogether.  There is no way that an .htaccess error can be at fault here.
At this point... I'm STUMPED.
I cannot find any sort of ssl.conf file anywhere on the server.  None of the optional conf files seem to have any mention of this domain - or even of ssl.  The plan here was to do what the other three (working) domains on the VPS do, which is to use Cloudflare's built in SSL certs and let them handle all of that.  So we aren't even really running certs at all.
Where is this https redirection coming from?  How do I possibly troubleshoot this?  I've spent hours researching, and frustratingly, 90% of the advice is for end users - clear cookies/cache, try another browser, etc.  That's obviously not going to help here.
Thanks for any assistance.

I have done some extensive grep commands.  I cannot find a reference to my domain in any files aside from httpd.conf, the various logs, and the actual website files.
What gives?

After debugging the entire world, the issue turned out to be an incorrect A record in the DNS.  Hours of digging for nothing!
Thanks to anyone who tried to puzzle this with me.
